# Is it possible to use a custom font in a page but the user not be able to download it?

Tags: node.js, fonts, font-face, font-family, custom-font

I am using a custom font for a web page with font-face.

I use node as a back-end with express and I have the custom font in a "public" folder. Is it possible to hide somehow the font from the user to be able to download it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to hide somehow the font from the user to be able to download it?

No, it is not.  If the font is usable in the user's browser, then by necessity, the browser downloaded the font.  If the browser downloads the font, so can anyone else.

This is the architecture of the web.  The same is true for images displayed in the browser, HTML displayed in the browser or Javascript code run in the browser or any resource used in the browser.  All are available to the end user if they so choose to access them directly.